# VAE input data scaling

Tags: artificial-intelligence, scaling, autoencoder, gradient

Variational Autoencoders (VAE) are quite a heaving concept themselves. Non-surprisingly most post, comments and tutorials focus on the theory and architecture, but most also fail to address the topic of data scaling. While experimenting with VAEs I have come across a (to me) surprising read flag that the way the data is scaled into an VAE is very important and I could not put my head around it what is the explanation.

To visualize the following issue descripting access the Notebook here: https://github.com/mobias17/VAE-Input-Scaling/blob/master/VAE%20Input%20Scaling.ipynb

Let’s assume the goal is to reconstruct a sine wave (e.g. a sound wave) by a VAE. When I feed the standardized data through the model, it is only able to approximate values between -1 and 1. Obviously, the quick answer would be to normalize the data. Still, this leads to the following questions:

1)  What is the rational that the VAE can only approximate values between -1 and 1? (is it the gaussian reparameterization, vanishing gradients?)

2)   Is there a way to overcome this boundary (model changes)?

3)  What is the best practice to scale data for a VAE? Should the data be normalized over the std dev?

[Results showing Sutputs are between -1 & 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKknC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Variational autoencoders can approximate values in any range. The problem here is with this particular model's architecture.

The decoder of this VAE uses as the last layer keras.layers.LSTM.
[This layer's default activation function is tanh,](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) and the tanh function outputs values in the range (-1,1). This is why the model cannot generate values outside that range.

However, if we change the activation function to, say, linear, replacing

```
decoder_mean = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)
```

with

```
decoder_mean = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True, activation=None)
```

the VAE now can approximate the data. This is the result I got after training for 100 epochs.
[image]

The general recommendation is to ensure that the data you are trying to approximate lies in the range of the function you are using to approximate it, either by scaling the data or choosing a more expressive function.